# get first element from jsonb list of strings postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.6

I have a List which is stored in my table as a jsonb and need a native query to get the first element from this jsonb column

Tried using jsonb_array_elements_text but couldn't get it to work.

```
select col from tbl;
```

returns:

```
["abc", "def", "etc"]
```

I need a query which can just return me abc

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) that picks the n-th element of an array:

```
select col ->> 0 as first_element
from tbl;
```

Note that unlike Postgres native arrays, the first element in a JSON array has the index `0`