# postgresql getting the first string in the json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a script

```
select s."name", s.id, jsonb_agg(distinct t.cuisine) as ncuisine 
from smfood s
left join food_taxonomy t on s.name ilike concat('%',t.keywords,'%')
where t.cuisine is not null
group by "name" , id
```

that gets me this result right here:

[image]

im trying to just get the first category in the ncuisine column so it only shows 1 cuisine category. How can i do that on my script?

Comment: the answer is -> 0

Comment: without knowing the tables , data we really can't understand what first means so produce a [mre]

Comment: Look into : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56937212/8843451